# Length validation for int property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any validation for integers where user can write only exact length of integer.

There is [Range] but that works only for range of value.
There is also [MaxLength] and [MinLength] for string but is there something like that for integers.

I need property that has type int but which allows to enter exactly 11 numbers.
I think one option is [Range(10000000000, 99999999999)], but that is awful.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Which product are you using, ASP.NET Framework or ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 1):

Change the type to a string and use a simple Regex of `^\d{11}$`. Otherwise you could build your own validator.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a textbox which can just typed numbers

in **jquery** side you can write

```
$("#txtNumberField").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which !== 8 && e.which !== 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

in **cshtml** side you can write like this

```
@(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberField).HtmlAttributes(new { @Id = "txtNumberField", style = "width:100%", maxlength = "10", required = "required", validationMessage = "Enter Number" }))
```

max length is **10** because max int value is **2,147,483,647**